# Devise Gem, adding builders and change redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im using the 'Devise' gem on a rails 3.1.1 app for creating users and signing in, but i need to add fields for profile as @user.build_profile but i dont know where to add this, i also need to change the default redirect_to after signing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the fields that you need to your models just as you normally would through a migration. If you are using the default devise views through `rails generate devise:views`, then you will want to add your fields to the `new` and `edit` views inside of the Registration views in devise.

As for changing the default redirect after sign_in, I would start with reading the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in). You can simply add to your application controller:

```
 protected

      def stored_location_for(resource)
        nil
      end

      def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        #path to which you wish to redirect
      end
end
```

This will allow you to customize that route. You can also look at the registrations controller within devise to see the other methods that you can override.

Edit:

Overriding the controller:

You would create your own controller that inherits from `Devise::RegistrationsController`. From there you only need to specify the methods that you need to override, and not every single one. For instance:

```
def create
  build_resource
  resource.build_profile

  if resource.save
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up
    redirect_to after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    render_with_scope :new
  end
end
```

Then add the above lines for `stored location` and `after_sign_in_path`. You also have to tell Devise in your `routes.rb` to use your new controller with, `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'your_controller_name }` I have an example of this on my blog, and the full source is on Github.

Comment: i need to add fiels from another model using nested attributes

Comment: So you make sure that your User model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile`. You would then need to override the Devise registrations controller to have your own create action with `@user.profile.build`, obviously creating the appropriate relationships between User and Profile.

Comment: thatt was the question. how do i overwrite the controller

Comment: I added to my answer to show you the basics of overriding the controller.

Comment: so i should do something like

  def new
    resource = build_resource({})
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
    resource.build_profile
  end

Comment: No, I think that you only need override the create action just as I have posted above. That's the beauty of the Devise modularity, you can override just the actions that you need.

Answer (score 1):

Or you just override `build_resource`

```
def build_resource *a, &b
  super
  resource.build_profile
end
```